# Proper term for "converting" time domain data to frequency domain

Tags: mathematics, science

I had difficulty deciding if this should go in stack overflow, electrical engineering or here, English language. Forgive me if it's in the wrong place.

I am looking for a word that describes the action (process?) of converting data from time domain to frequency domain.

A term we sometimes use at work (incorrectly) is "decimation" which *actually* refers to the **reduction of the sampling rate of data**. It's important to note here that I am referring to *only* going from time to frequency domain.

Am I overthinking this? Is the answer simply "converting"?

Comment: I believe the standard term is *transform* - as in *Fourier transform*.

Comment: @michael.hor257k That sounds correct, but maybe missing some detail. It's not immediately clear what one would mean by just "transform" without a good deal of context. "Domain transform" perhaps?

Comment: Yep, Fourier transform and Laplace transform.  One might argue that the general concept is a form of *inversion*, but I've never heard that term applied.

Comment: @HotLicks While I agree with both of you, I think it's lacking specificity. One could transform data in either direction, but I want to refer specifically to going from time to frequency.

Comment: @MatthewGoulart I don't think there is a single-word term for it; you just need to specify the type of transform, e.g. DCT. Or say time-to-frequency transform.

Comment: In searching the web I found several locations referred to it as decomposing, as in  "The Fourier Transform is an important image processing tool which is used to decompose an image into its sine and cosine components."

Comment: @KarlRookey I like that a lot, because with only a little context you could say "we are decomposing/recomposing the data". In case someone is wondering *why* that makes sense, it's because an arbitrary wave is *composed* of any number of pure sine waves. In *decomposing* the original waveform, we are separating it's components in order to analyze them.

Comment: I agree with half of the comment from @HotLicks: conversions between time and frequency are given by the Fourier transform. The Laplace transform is similar in that the transformed variable has the dimensions of frequency (if the original variable was time), but it lacks the oscillatory character that "frequency" ordinarily connotes. (Formally, it behaves like an imaginary frequency.)  So I"d just use "Fourier transform" for this question.

Answer (score 2):

A common term for what you describe is **spectral analysis**, where a signal originally expressed as a sequence of values at discrete time steps  is re-expressed as a linear combination of sines and cosines at discrete frequencies.

There may be a specific domain of knowledge where the practitioners use a single word. For example, an astronomer might “spectrograph” a light source. A bench technician might “FFT” a complex signal. At the more mathematical level, however, single words like “projection” or “mapping” are usually not limited to just the time-to-frequency direction.